# How to update content of child window (c++) even if window size does not change

Tags: window, refresh, repaint, redraw

The content of my application window is only updated when i change the window size.

Details:
I have a windows application written in c++ and compiled with mingw64.
Within WinMain, i do a CreateWindowW for the WndProc.
In the WndProc callback, i have a WM_CREATE from where i setup all initial data to be shown and do a

```
case WM_CREATE:
  hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
  doAllTheDrawings(hdc);
  EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
  break;
```

After that, i have my child window showing all the diagrams with initial values.

After that, in the background, some data change, and i want to update the diagrams.
When resizing the child window, it immediately updates the data shown to the new values, as the WM_PAINT is called

```
case WM_PAINT:
  hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
  doAllTheDrawings(hdc);
  EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
  break;
```

Now i want to update my diagrams even if i do not change the window size. Therefore i added

```
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
  hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
  doAllTheDrawings(hdc);
  EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
  break;
```

So i expect that the diagrams update as soon as i press the left mousebutton.
I can see that WM_LBUTTONDOWN is called (as i have a few other actions done then), but the diagrams do not update until i resize the window.

What am i doing wrong?
How can i force the diagrams to update, i.e. the window to be repainted?
Just calling WM_PAINT manually does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i found a solution:
The whole creation of the diagrams, which i so far did on WM_CREATE and WM_LBUTTONDOWN is only required under WM_PAINT.
On WM_CREATE and WM_LBUTTONDOWN, only

```
  InvalidateRect(hwnd,NULL,TRUE);
```

needs to be called. This 'flushes' the client area and then calls WM_PAINT and recreates it all.
Refer to

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-invalidaterect

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).